# overflow hidden not working

Tags: css, overflow, scrollbars

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;margin-top:37px;background color:#06A1FF;height:130px;width:100%;border-bottom:1px solid black;padding-top:20px;padding-left:20px">
```

For some reason, the overflow:hidden doesn't seem to work as it keeps producing horizontal scrollbars.

Please help me.

Comment: please reproduce the problem on www.jsfiddle.net, so we can see...

Comment: and background color should be background-color

Comment: `background color:#06A1FF;` needs to be changed to `background-color:#06A1FF;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the overflow setting is not working is because overflow handles the overflow of the content, not that of the element itself.

So choose [bookcasey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8459581/757830) and add `margin-left: -20px`, or add `overflow: hidden` to the parent element.

Answer (score 2):

Add `margin-left:-20px;`, currently the width of the `div` is 100% + 20px because of the padding.